# Has Microsoft abandoned CNTK?

Tags: cntk

I want to know if CNTK dead? Release notes on GitHub dated 03/31/2019: "Today’s 2.7 release will be the last main release of CNTK." I've spent months developing software using CNTK and now it appears to be a waste of time and money. I've search for an answer on numerous sites and still no answer. stackoverflow is one of the sites recommend by Microsoft.

Comment: It will no longer be developed. There was never official **support** so you aren't losing that. However it looks to be fully fledged already, there may not be much to gain by continued updates to it. They said they may do bug-fixes, but it appears that Microsoft has put CNTK in a position where they can use it without maintaining it anymore.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I wasn't expecting support but tech changes so much & so quickly that it is risky banking on outdated software. I guess I'll have to start over with something else.

Answer (score 15):

From KedengMS, one of the maintainers for CNTK. Reposted from [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/issues/3646).

> Thanks for all the CNTK supporters, and I am privileged to have worked
>   on it, and learned a lot in the process. You can continue to use CNTK
>   for training and inference in the way it currently is, as other
>   Microsoft internal teams that still runs old models even in
>   BrainScript or NDL. Stopping adding new features does not mean CNTK is
>   no longer open source, it just means that going forward, there will be
>   no new GPU support (say, CUDA 11+), and no major new features added.
>   For different user scenarios, I think you may have different choices:
>
> - Deep learning newcomers: IMO CNTK is still a good entry to understand basics of deep learning, if you found CNTK
>     documents/tutorials/examples useful. Once you learnt the basic, it
>     won't be too hard to switch between frameworks. However, the DL field
>     is changing rapidly and CNTK has already lagged behind in a lot of
>     ways, so if you need more advanced features like dynamic graph,
>     PyTorch would be a better choice.
> - Model maintainers: If you already have CNTK models working, and to maintain it just means training with new data, you can continue to use
>     CNTK the way you currently use it. Actually, teams inside Microsoft
>     are doing this too. If there are serious bugs preventing productivity,
>     they still will be fixed. For inference, you can continue to use CNTK
>     C/C++/Python/C#/Java APIs, or you may export CNTK models in ONNX
>     format, and use ONNX Runtime or ORT as a slimmer and faster inference
>     engine. You'll be surprised to find how much faster it is comparing to
>     CNTK, and how slimmer the setup is (forget about OpenMPI when you just
>     need inference!). ORT currently provides C/C++/Python/C# interfaces.
> - Model builders: If you have CNTK model, and want to use features that are not currently supported in CNTK, please consider switch to
>     other frameworks like TensorFlow/PyTorch/etc. Our team has done lots
>     of data reader work inside PyTorch to ensure teams in Microsoft can
>     switch from CNTK to PyTorch. Besides, we are also in the process of
>     migrating CNTK specific distributed trainer like BMUF to PyTorch.
>     Hopefully you'll find that useful too when migrating your model.
>
> The good thing about open source is that the community can continue to
>   fork/evolve if needed, unlike other Microsoft products that only ship
>   binaries (Win7 I am looking at you).

Comment: Basically abandoned, just don't want to admit it in one word

Comment: @snowflake what is ORT ? do you have a link? because I cannot find anything about it

Comment: @MarioM ORT is ONNX RuntIme. https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime