# When will CNTK wheel be released for Python 3.7?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, cntk

I wanted to use cntk for anaconda,but on microsoft there is only link provided uptil version 3.5.
Is there any othetr way around that I can use cntk without downgrading python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Has Microsoft abandoned CNTK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55831498/has-microsoft-abandoned-cntk)

Answer (score 0):

create a environment and install python 3.5 or 3.6 to use cntk

```
conda create -n env_name python=3.5(version want to use)
```

after creating activate env

in windows `conda activate env_name`

in linux `source activate env_name`

after your activating install cntk using `pip install cntk`